# Determine the value of $a + b $ if the equation $\vert x^2 - 2ax +b\vert=8$ has only three real roots, which are the sides of a right triangle.

Tags: number-theory, problem-solving

Determine the value of $a + b $ if the equation $\vert x^2 - 2ax +b\vert=8$ has only three real roots, which are the sides of a right triangle.

Ive spent like an hour trying to figure out how to approach this. Please assist

From the 2018 IMC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the equation to have three roots we need
$$b=a^2-8$$
such that a local maximum occurs at the point $(x,y)=(a,8)$ and two other points intersect with the line $y=8$ at $(x,y)=(a\pm4,8)$. If these three roots are sides of a right triangle then
$$(a-4)^2+a^2=(a+4)^2$$
$$a^2-8a+16+a^2=a^2+8a+16$$
$$a(a-16)=0$$
$$a=16$$
as we need $a\gt0$. Hence the value of $a+b$ is
$$16+16^2-8=264$$

Comment: How do you know $ b=a^2-8$  ?

Comment: As I explained, we need a local maximum at $y=8$ at the vertex of the parabola which occurs when $x=a$. This is the only way to get three roots.